# ExecutionError":"Smart contract panicked: panicked at 'Should be initialized before usage' error while running test:deploy [NEAR PROTOCOL]

Tags: javascript, testing, rust, smartcontracts, nearprotocol

I am trying to run 'yarn test:deploy' on this repo [Coin Flip](https://github.com/near-apps/coin-flip) and getting all the test cases failed. I haven't edited the code yet. This is the terminal output I am encountering:

> yarn run v1.22.17 $ yarn dev:deploy && yarn test $ yarn
> build:contracts && rm -rf neardev && (near dev-deploy || exit 0) &&
> yarn patch:config $ (cd contracts && ./build.sh) warning: unused
> imports: `Base58PublicKey`, `Promise`, `PublicKey`  -->
> src/lib.rs:3:44   | 3 |     env, near_bindgen, AccountId, Balance,
> PublicKey, Promise,   |
> ^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^ 4 |     collections::{ UnorderedMap }, 5 |
> json_types::{ U128, Base58PublicKey },   |
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   |   = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default
>
> warning: unused import: `serde::Serialize`  --> src/lib.rs:7:5   | 7 |
> use serde::Serialize;   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> warning: `basic-token` (lib) generated 2 warnings
> Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.10s Starting deployment. Account id: dev-1643646762507-80701581766916, node:
> https://rpc.testnet.near.org, helper: https://helper.testnet.near.org,
> file: ./out/main.wasm Transaction Id
> EgJ3v7HW5oea4aUmWN35E8DBD3DznRz8pKReWaRdiAx1 Done deploying to
> dev-1643646762507-80701581766916 $ node ./utils/patch-config.js Done!
> $ REACT_APP_ENV=dev jest app.test.js --useStderr   console.log
> Loading Credentials:
> /root/.near-credentials/testnet/dev-1643646762507-80701581766916.json
>
> ```
>   at Object.<anonymous> (test/near-utils.js:16:9)
> ```
>
> console.log
> Receipts: JCteRULCHjv3xCqUBQrrkGibgNMFPFzp2aryB3tSpB2r, 4yzsCsEX8w13T3S1jnYTnrHwfwh8Va7b5BMCHgALqke7
>
> ```
>   at Account.printLogsAndFailures (node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:62:21)
> ```
>
> console.warn
> **Failure [test-1643646780358-957084]: Error: {"index":0,"account_id":"test-1643646780358-957084","predecessor_id":"dev-1643646762507-80701581766916","registrar_account_id":"registrar","kind":{"account_id":"test-1643646780358-957084","registrar_account_id":"registrar","predecessor_id":"dev-1643646762507-80701581766916"}}**
>
> ```
>   30 |   const contractAccount = new Account(connection, contractName);
>   31 |   const newKeyPair = KeyPair.fromRandom("ed25519");
> > 32 |   await contractAccount.createAccount(
>      |   ^
>   33 |     accountId,
>   34 |     newKeyPair.publicKey,
>   35 |     new BN(parseNearAmount(fundingAmount))
>
>   at Account.printLogsAndFailures (node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:65:25)
>   at Account.signAndSendTransaction (node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:144:14)
>   at createAccount (test/test-utils.js:32:3)
>   at getAccount (test/test-utils.js:95:10)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (test/app.test.js:20:11)
> ```
>
> console.log
> Receipts: DbXqegvztxpwYgaAhn5ougLoa6SFCJqK7WVPL2UBfG5H, GWECkQApTXTdNGRPUabuF3grVK451PXBwX5e5qU4NtaF
>
> ```
>   at Account.printLogsAndFailures (node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:62:21)
> ```
>
> console.warn
> **Failure [dev-1643646762507-80701581766916]: Error: {"index":0,"kind":{"ExecutionError":"Smart contract panicked: panicked
> at 'Should be initialized before usage', src/lib.rs:25:9"}}**
>
> ```
>   29 |      test('check deposit', async () => {
>   30 |         contract = await getContract(alice)
> > 31 |              await contract.deposit({}, GAS, parseNearAmount('19'));
>      |              ^
>   32 |         const credits = await contract.get_credits({ account_id: alice.accountId })
>   33 |         expect(credits).toEqual(parseNearAmount('19'))
>   34 |      });
>
>   at Account.printLogsAndFailures (node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:65:25)
>   at Account.signAndSendTransaction (node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:144:14)
>   at node_modules/near-api-js/lib/contract.js:49:39
>   at Object.<anonymous> (test/app.test.js:31:3)
> ```
>
> console.log
> Receipt: CETdj9Wn8idE52xn9pRWVq1MQy3ADWofcxNcg9sYX6Ed
>
> ```
>   at Account.printLogsAndFailures (node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:62:21)
> ```
>
> console.warn
> **Failure [dev-1643646762507-80701581766916]: Error: {"index":0,"kind":{"ExecutionError":"Smart contract panicked: panicked
> at 'Should be initialized before usage', src/lib.rs:25:9"}}**
>
> ```
>   37 |         
>   38 |         for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
> > 39 |             const rand = await contract.play({}, GAS);
>      |                          ^
>   40 |             console.log(rand)
>   41 |             const credits = await contract.get_credits({ account_id: alice.accountId })
>   42 |             console.log(credits)
>
>   at Account.printLogsAndFailures (node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:65:25)
>   at Account.signAndSendTransaction (node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:144:14)
>   at node_modules/near-api-js/lib/contract.js:49:39
>   at Object.<anonymous> (test/app.test.js:39:26)
> ```
>
> **FAIL**  test/app.test.js (17.076 s)   deploy contract
> dev-1643646762507-80701581766916
> ✕ contract hash (3 ms)
> ✕ check deposit (3837 ms)
> ✕ check play (2368 ms)
>
> ● **deploy contract dev-1643646762507-80701581766916 › contract hash**
>
> ```
> {"index":0,"account_id":"test-1643646780358-957084","predecessor_id":"dev-1643646762507-80701581766916","registrar_account_id":"registrar","kind":{"account_id":"test-1643646780358-957084","registrar_account_id":"registrar","predecessor_id":"dev-1643646762507-80701581766916"}}
>
>   30 |   const contractAccount = new Account(connection, contractName);
>   31 |   const newKeyPair = KeyPair.fromRandom("ed25519");
> > 32 |   await contractAccount.createAccount(
>      |   ^
>   33 |     accountId,
>   34 |     newKeyPair.publicKey,
>   35 |     new BN(parseNearAmount(fundingAmount))
>
>   at Object.parseResultError (node_modules/near-api-js/lib/utils/rpc_errors.js:48:29)
>   at Account.signAndSendTransaction (node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:151:36)
>   at createAccount (test/test-utils.js:32:3)
>   at getAccount (test/test-utils.js:95:10)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (test/app.test.js:20:11)
> ```
>
> ● **deploy contract dev-1643646762507-80701581766916 › check deposit**
>
> ```
> {"index":0,"account_id":"test-1643646780358-957084","predecessor_id":"dev-1643646762507-80701581766916","registrar_account_id":"registrar","kind":{"account_id":"test-1643646780358-957084","registrar_account_id":"registrar","predecessor_id":"dev-1643646762507-80701581766916"}}
>
>   30 |   const contractAccount = new Account(connection, contractName);
>   31 |   const newKeyPair = KeyPair.fromRandom("ed25519");
> > 32 |   await contractAccount.createAccount(
>      |   ^
>   33 |     accountId,
>   34 |     newKeyPair.publicKey,
>   35 |     new BN(parseNearAmount(fundingAmount))
>
>   at Object.parseResultError (node_modules/near-api-js/lib/utils/rpc_errors.js:48:29)
>   at Account.signAndSendTransaction (node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:151:36)
>   at createAccount (test/test-utils.js:32:3)
>   at getAccount (test/test-utils.js:95:10)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (test/app.test.js:20:11)
> ```
>
> ● **deploy contract dev-1643646762507-80701581766916 › check deposit**
>
> ```
> {"index":0,"kind":{"ExecutionError":"Smart contract panicked: panicked at 'Should be initialized before usage', src/lib.rs:25:9"}}
>
>   29 |      test('check deposit', async () => {
>   30 |         contract = await getContract(alice)
> > 31 |              await contract.deposit({}, GAS, parseNearAmount('19'));
>      |              ^
>   32 |         const credits = await contract.get_credits({ account_id: alice.accountId })
>   33 |         expect(credits).toEqual(parseNearAmount('19'))
>   34 |      });
>
>   at Object.parseResultError (node_modules/near-api-js/lib/utils/rpc_errors.js:48:29)
>   at Account.signAndSendTransaction (node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:151:36)
>   at node_modules/near-api-js/lib/contract.js:49:39
>   at Object.<anonymous> (test/app.test.js:31:3)
> ```
>
> ● **deploy contract dev-1643646762507-80701581766916 › check play**
>
> ```
> {"index":0,"account_id":"test-1643646780358-957084","predecessor_id":"dev-1643646762507-80701581766916","registrar_account_id":"registrar","kind":{"account_id":"test-1643646780358-957084","registrar_account_id":"registrar","predecessor_id":"dev-1643646762507-80701581766916"}}
>
>   30 |   const contractAccount = new Account(connection, contractName);
>   31 |   const newKeyPair = KeyPair.fromRandom("ed25519");
> > 32 |   await contractAccount.createAccount(
>      |   ^
>   33 |     accountId,
>   34 |     newKeyPair.publicKey,
>   35 |     new BN(parseNearAmount(fundingAmount))
>
>   at Object.parseResultError (node_modules/near-api-js/lib/utils/rpc_errors.js:48:29)
>   at Account.signAndSendTransaction (node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:151:36)
>   at createAccount (test/test-utils.js:32:3)
>   at getAccount (test/test-utils.js:95:10)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (test/app.test.js:20:11)
> ```
>
> ● **deploy contract dev-1643646762507-80701581766916 › check play**
>
> ```
> {"index":0,"kind":{"ExecutionError":"Smart contract panicked: panicked at 'Should be initialized before usage', src/lib.rs:25:9"}}
>
>   37 |         
>   38 |         for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
> > 39 |             const rand = await contract.play({}, GAS);
>      |                          ^
>   40 |             console.log(rand)
>   41 |             const credits = await contract.get_credits({ account_id: alice.accountId })
>   42 |             console.log(credits)
>
>   at Object.parseResultError (node_modules/near-api-js/lib/utils/rpc_errors.js:48:29)
>   at Account.signAndSendTransaction (node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:151:36)
>   at node_modules/near-api-js/lib/contract.js:49:39
>   at Object.<anonymous> (test/app.test.js:39:26)
> ```

```
> Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
> Tests:       3 failed, 3 total
> Snapshots:   0 total
> Time:        17.145 s, estimated 35 s
> Ran all test suites matching /app.test.js/i. error Command failed with exit
> code 1. info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for
> documentation about this command. error Command failed with exit code
> 1. info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is the state of my machine:

```
node --version
v16.13.2

npm --version
8.1.2

near --version
3.1.0

rustc --version
rustc 1.58.1 (db9d1b20b 2022-01-20)

yarn --version
1.22.17
```

Comment: Did you do a ‘yarn’ or ‘npm install’ before running the test script?

Comment: Yes @John I did 'yarn' before running the test scripts:

`yarn
yarn install v1.22.17
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.50s.`

Answer (score 1):

the error you're seeing is because you need to call the `init` function on the contract.

Comment: I think `await initContract(alice.accountId);` in Line 21 of app.test.js does that

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are a lot of dependencies needed before running the project. From the top of the Readme - npm, node (latest versions) and rust lang seem like a requirement. Try following the readme step by step and see if the errors persist.

Comment: This is the state of my machine:

`node --version
v16.13.2

npm --version
8.1.2

near --version
3.1.0

rustc --version
rustc 1.60.0-nightly (08df8b81d 2022-01-30)

yarn --version
1.22.17`

Comment: Okay, seems good! There's also this  - 
cd server 
yarn && yarn start

The server should be started when you are running commands on the project. You can run the commands above in a separate terminal window and  leave it running. It's your server - it should serve, continuously.

Comment: Hey @KROM thanks for actively helping me out. I tried starting the server in a new terminal and running yarn test on another and the problem still persists. Have you cloned the repo and tried running the same commands? If it runs on your machine then I might consider reinstalling everything. FYI I am using WSL.

Answer (score 0):

Please you need to initialize your contract after deployment.

run: `near call mycontract.myaccount.testnet init --accountId=myaccount.testnet`

Then call you smartcontract.